# my dropdown content keeps going to the right

Tags: css

I have a drop down menu, with different sections. The content below is supposed to appear after I hover over the certain section. The issue that I'm having is that the different sections appear to the right, when I actually want them centered.

Thank you guys in advanced! I appreciate the help.

[Here's what I want it to look, and how the first one looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69ChD.png)

[But this is how they look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIIPK.png)

[Another example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZJzw.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="firstContainer" id="firstsection">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="middleColumn">
                        <div class="circularImage">
                            <img src="killua.jpeg">
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="name">ERICK LOJANO</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class = "secondContainer">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-12">
                    <div class="middleColumn">
                    <h1 class="name"><br></h1>
                        
                    <div class="dropDown">
                        <button class= "dropButton"> about me</button>
                        <div class="dropDown-content">
                        <p class="text">I'm currently a rising senior majoring in computer science at Brooklyn College. First generation college student.</p>
                        <p class="text">Some of my hobbies include gaming, watching/playing soccer, programming, and photography.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                    <div class="dropDown">
                        <button class= "dropButton"> experience</button>
                        <div class="dropDown-content">
                        <p class="name"> hello hello hello</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                        
                     <div class="dropDown">
                        <button class= "dropButton"> projects</button>
                        <div class="dropDown-content">
                        <p class="name"> hello hello hello</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                    
                     <div class="dropDown">
                        <button class= "dropButton"> socials</button>
                        <div class="dropDown-content">
                        <p class="name"> hello hello hello</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
    header, footer {
    display: block;
    }

    body{
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    }

    .firstContainer{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 1%;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    }

    .secondContainer{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 1%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    }

    .row{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center
    }

    .row::after{
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    }


    .col-1 {width: 8.33% }
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%}
    .col-3 {width: 25%}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%}
    .col-6 {width: 50%}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%}
    .col-9 {width: 75%}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%}
    .col-12 {width: 100%}

    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    /* CUSTOM STYLES */

    #firstsection{
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 2%, rgba(66, 174, 219,1) 100%);
    }

    .middleColumn{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    }

    div.circularImage{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    h1.name{
    color: ghostwhite;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Mukta Malar';
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0;
    }

    p.text{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 5px;
    
    }

    .dropButton{
    background-color: azure;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5%;
    }

    .dropDown{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropDown-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: beige;
    width: 400%;
    top: 110%;
    border-radius: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropDown-content a{
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }

    .dropDown:hover .dropDown-content{
    display: block;
    
    }

    .dropDown:hover .dropButton{
    background-color:cornflowerblue;
    color: beige;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a functioning version of your code ?

Comment: Seems like the drop down content is relative to the item you click on, Whereas it should be relative to the container holding the items you click on, Include the HTML or even better a working snippet illustrating the issue

Comment: insert your html and we will try to help you

Comment: @ZohirSalak I've made edits to my post, thank you!

Comment: @bluebird I've made some edits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with how you built it.
Imho it's much better to just make a **container** of your 4 elements and make your **absolute positioned relative** to it.

Here is an updated version of your code.
All I did was to add a container in html and style it.
I also removed some css from `.dropDown` and `.dropDown-content`

```css
 header, footer {
    display: block;
    }

    body{
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    }

    .firstContainer{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 1%;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    }

    .secondContainer{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 1%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    }

    .row{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center
    }

    .row::after{
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    }


    .col-1 {width: 8.33% }
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%}
    .col-3 {width: 25%}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%}
    .col-6 {width: 50%}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%}
    .col-9 {width: 75%}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%}
    .col-12 {width: 100%}

    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    /* CUSTOM STYLES */

    #firstsection{
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 2%, rgba(66, 174, 219,1) 100%);
    }

    .middleColumn{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    }

    div.circularImage{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    h1.name{
    color: ghostwhite;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Mukta Malar';
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0;
    }

    p.text{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 5px;
    
    }

    .dropButton{
    background-color: azure;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5%;
    }

.dropDown-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 420px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
    .dropDown-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: beige;
    top: 110%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    border-radius: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropDown-content a{
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }

    .dropDown:hover .dropDown-content{
    display: block;
    
    }

    .dropDown:hover .dropButton{
    background-color:cornflowerblue;
    color: beige;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="firstContainer" id="firstsection">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="middleColumn">
                        <div class="circularImage">
                            <img src="killua.jpeg">
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="name">ERICK LOJANO</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class = "secondContainer">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-12">
                    <div class="middleColumn">
                    <h1 class="name"><br></h1>
                    <div class="dropDown-container">
                    <div class="dropDown">
                        <button class= "dropButton"> about me</button>
                        <div class="dropDown-content">
                        <p class="text">I'm currently a rising senior majoring in computer science at Brooklyn College. First generation college student.</p>
                        <p class="text">Some of my hobbies include gaming, watching/playing soccer, programming, and photography.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                    <div class="dropDown">
                        <button class= "dropButton"> experience</button>
                        <div class="dropDown-content">
                        <p class="name"> hello hello hello</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                        
                     <div class="dropDown">
                        <button class= "dropButton"> projects</button>
                        <div class="dropDown-content">
                        <p class="name"> hello hello hello</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                    
                     <div class="dropDown">
                        <button class= "dropButton"> socials</button>
                        <div class="dropDown-content">
                        <p class="name"> hello hello hello</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this worked! thank you very much. I understand now, I should've made a container for the drop down menu so the content would appear below it. Rather than having the content appear below each of the elements.